# Java JAX-RS 2.0 + Jersey + Jetty Security

Tags: java, rest, jetty, authorization, jax-rs

I am building a RESTful Web Service in which I have a set of commands that should only be used by admins. Ideally I would have two ports setup, both with Server-side SSL, however one port would require client SSL. I would like to know how I could separate resources by port. Alternatively, I could have the system setup to use @RolesAllowed for each resource, In that case I would need to know how to set the role of the user (by port would be great). So far I have a http and https port setup and working. I also have all the resources setup.

It might also be good to know that the two files shown below are the only ones used to run with webservice. there are no container files etc. 
keep in mind that not all code is complete. Here is the code:

```
import org.eclipse.jetty.http.HttpVersion;
import org.eclipse.jetty.server.*;
import org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletContextHandler;
import org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder;
import org.eclipse.jetty.util.ssl.SslContextFactory;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;


public class Core {

static String jettyKeystore = "Assets/keys/keystore";
//http://www.eclipse.org/jetty/documentation/current/configuring-ssl.html

public static void main(String args[]) throws FileNotFoundException {
    String keystorePath = System.getProperty(
            "example.keystore", jettyKeystore);
    File keyStoreFile = new File(keystorePath);
    if (!keyStoreFile.exists()) {
        throw new FileNotFoundException(keyStoreFile.getAbsolutePath());
    }

    ServletContextHandler context = new ServletContextHandler(ServletContextHandler.SESSIONS);
    context.setContextPath("/");

    int port = 8080;
    int securePort = 8084;

    HttpConfiguration httpConf = new HttpConfiguration();
    httpConf.setSecureScheme("https");
    httpConf.setSecurePort(securePort);
    httpConf.setOutputBufferSize(32768);

    Server jettyServer = new Server();
    ServerConnector http = new ServerConnector(jettyServer,
            new HttpConnectionFactory(httpConf));
    http.setPort(port);
    http.setIdleTimeout(30000);

    SslContextFactory sslContextFactory = new SslContextFactory();
    sslContextFactory.setKeyStorePath(keyStoreFile.getAbsolutePath());
    sslContextFactory.setKeyStorePassword("password");
    sslContextFactory.setKeyManagerPassword("password");
    //sslContextFactory.setNeedClientAuth(true);

    HttpConfiguration httpsConf = new HttpConfiguration(httpConf);
    httpsConf.addCustomizer(new SecureRequestCustomizer());


    ServerConnector https = new ServerConnector(jettyServer,
            new SslConnectionFactory(sslContextFactory, HttpVersion.HTTP_1_1.asString()),
            new HttpConnectionFactory(httpsConf));
    https.setPort(securePort);
    https.setIdleTimeout(500000);

    jettyServer.setConnectors(new Connector[]{http, https});


    jettyServer.setHandler(context);
    ServletHolder jerseyServlet = context.addServlet(
            org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.class,     "/*");

    jerseyServlet.setInitOrder(0);


    jerseyServlet.setInitParameter(
            "jersey.config.server.provider.classnames",
            RQHandler.class.getCanonicalName());


    try {
        jettyServer.start();
        System.err.println("Server Started on port: " + port + "," +          securePort);
        jettyServer.join();
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        jettyServer.destroy();
    }

}
}
```

Here is the resource file:

```
import com.mongodb.DB;
import com.mongodb.DBCollection;
import com.mongodb.DBCursor;
import com.mongodb.MongoClient;
import com.sun.xml.internal.messaging.saaj.packaging.mime.internet.ContentDisposition;

import java.io.*;
import java.net.UnknownHostException;

import javax.annotation.security.PermitAll;
import javax.annotation.security.RolesAllowed;
import javax.websocket.server.PathParam;
import javax.ws.rs.*;
import javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType;
import javax.ws.rs.core.Response;
import javax.ws.rs.core.StreamingOutput;

@Path("audio_archives")
public class RQHandler {
MongoClient mc;
DB db;
DBCollection audioCollection;
DBCollection videoCollection;

{
    try {
        mc = new MongoClient("localhost");
        db = mc.getDB("ziondb");
        audioCollection = db.getCollection("audio");
        videoCollection = db.getCollection("video");
    } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        System.out.println("exiting!");
        System.exit(0);
    }
}




@GET
@Path("getMedia")
@Produces(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)
public String getAllMedia(@QueryParam("type") String type){
    String DBreturn = "";

    if(type.toLowerCase().equals("audio")) {
        DBCursor cursor = audioCollection.find();

        try {
            while (cursor.hasNext()) {
                DBreturn += cursor.next();
            }
        } finally {
            cursor.close();
        }

    } else if(type.toLowerCase().equals("video")) {
        DBCursor cursor = videoCollection.find();

        try {
            while (cursor.hasNext()) {
                DBreturn += cursor.next();
            }
        } finally {
            cursor.close();
        }
    }

    if (DBreturn.equals("")) {
        DBreturn = "{ \"entries\" : \"null\" }";
    }
    return DBreturn;
}


@GET
@Path("getMediaFile")
@Produces({"video/mp4"}) //use application/type for downloadable file
public File getMediaFile(@QueryParam("type") String type,@QueryParam("resourceId") String id){
    String DBreturn = "";

    if(type.toLowerCase().equals("audio")) {
        DBCursor cursor = audioCollection.find();

        try {
            while (cursor.hasNext()) {
                DBreturn += cursor.next();
            }
        } finally {
            cursor.close();
        }

    } else if(type.toLowerCase().equals("video")) {
        DBCursor cursor = videoCollection.find();

        try {
            while (cursor.hasNext()) {
                DBreturn += cursor.next();
            }
        } finally {
            cursor.close();
        }
    }

    if (DBreturn.equals("")) {
        DBreturn = "{ \"entries\" : \"null\" }";
    }
    return (new File("/home/digitalblueeye/Downloads/SampleVideo_1280x720_50mb.mp4"));
}

@GET
@Path("getMediaStream")
@Produces({"video/mp4"}) //use application/type for downloadable file
public StreamingOutput getMediaStream(@QueryParam("type") String type, @QueryParam("resourceId") String id){
    return new StreamingOutput() {
        @Override
        public void write(OutputStream outputStream) throws IOException, WebApplicationException {
            File file = new File("/home/digitalblueeye/Downloads/SampleVideo_1280x720_50mb.mp4");
            outputStream = new FileOutputStream(file);
            outputStream.write(0);
        }
    };
}


//********************************************************

@GET
@Path("")
@Produces(MediaType.TEXT_HTML)
public static File home() {

    return (new File("Assets/index.html"));
}

@GET
@Path("developers")
@Produces(MediaType.TEXT_HTML)
public static File sysInfo() {

    return (new File("Assets/manual.html"));
}

@GET
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
@Path("list_by_date")
public String listByDate(@QueryParam("model") String model,
                         @QueryParam("from") String fromDate,
                         @QueryParam("to") String toDate,
                         @QueryParam("quota") String quota) {

    return null;
}

@GET
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
@Path("list_by_param")
public String listByParam(@QueryParam("model") String model,
                          @QueryParam("param_type") String paramType,
                          @QueryParam("param") String param,
                          @QueryParam("quota") String quota) {
    return null;
}

@GET
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
@Path("list_files")
public String listFile(@QueryParam("id") String id) {
    return null;
}

@GET
@Produces("application/mp3,application/wav")
@Path("get_file")
public File getFile(@QueryParam("id") String id) {
    return null;
}

@GET
@Produces("audio/mp3,audio/wav")
@Path("stream_file")
public File streamFile(@QueryParam("id") String id) {
    return null;
}

private byte[] readFromStream(InputStream stream) throws IOException {
    ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();

    byte[] buffer = new byte[1000];
    int wasRead = 0;
    do {
        wasRead = stream.read(buffer);
        if (wasRead > 0) {
            baos.write(buffer, 0, wasRead);
        }
    } while (wasRead > -1);
    return baos.toByteArray();

}

@PUT
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
@Path("get_auth_secret")
public void get_auth_secret(InputStream is) throws IOException {
    byte[] bytes = readFromStream(is);
    String input = new String(bytes);
    System.out.println(input);
}

@POST
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
@Path("update")//update reources
public void putstuff(InputStream is) throws IOException {
    byte[] bytes = readFromStream(is);
    String input = new String(bytes);
    System.out.println(input);
}

@DELETE
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)//use json for batch delete
@Path("delete")//delete reources
public void deletestuff(InputStream is) throws IOException {
    byte[] bytes = readFromStream(is);
    String input = new String(bytes);
    System.out.println(input);
}

@PUT
@Consumes("application/mp3,application/wav")
@Path("create")//create resources
public void createstuff(InputStream is) throws IOException {
    byte[] bytes = readFromStream(is);
    String input = new String(bytes);
    System.out.println(input);
}

/*

@POST
@Path("/upload")
@Consumes(MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA)
public Response uploadFile(
        @FormParam("file") InputStream fileInputStream,
        @QueryParam("filename") String filename) {

    String filePath = "FileStore/audio/" + filename;

    // save the file to the server
    saveFile(fileInputStream, filePath);

    String output = "File saved to server location : " + filePath;

    return Response.status(200).entity(output).build();

}

// save uploaded file to a defined location on the server
private void saveFile(InputStream uploadedInputStream,
                      String serverLocation) {

    try {
        OutputStream outpuStream = new FileOutputStream(new File(serverLocation));
        int read = 0;
        byte[] bytes = new byte[1024];

        outpuStream = new FileOutputStream(new File(serverLocation));
        while ((read = uploadedInputStream.read(bytes)) != -1) {
            outpuStream.write(bytes, 0, read);
        }
        outpuStream.flush();
        outpuStream.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {

        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}

@POST
@Path("/upload")
@Consumes(MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA)
public Response uploadFile(
        @FormDataParam("file") InputStream inputStream,
        @FormDataParam("file") FormDataContentDisposition formDataContentDisposition) {
    String fileName = formDataContentDisposition.getFileName();

    String filePath = saveFile(inputStream, fileName);

    String output = "File: " + filePath;

    return Response.status(Response.Status.CREATED).entity(output).build();
}

@POST
@Path("/multi")
@Consumes(MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA)
public Response uploadFile(
        FormDataMultiPart form) {
    FormDataBodyPart filePart = form.getField("file");

    ContentDisposition headerOfFilePart = filePart.getContentDisposition();

    InputStream inputStream = filePart.getValueAs(InputStream.class);

    String filePath = saveFile(inputStream, headerOfFilePart.getFileName());

    String output = "File: " + filePath;

    return Response.status(Response.Status.CREATED).entity(output).build();
}

private String saveFile(InputStream inputStream, String fileName) {
    try {
        File file = File.createTempFile("temp", ".txt");
        OutputStream outputStream = new FileOutputStream(file);
        int read = 0;
        byte[] bytes = new byte[1024];

        while ((read = inputStream.read(bytes)) != -1) {
            outputStream.write(bytes, 0, read);
        }
        outputStream.flush();
        outputStream.close();
        return file.getAbsolutePath();
    } catch (Exception e) {

    }
    return "";
}
*/


//Media streaming with JAX-RS https://github.com/aruld/jersey-streaming
}
```

The methods I am looking to protect are PUT, POST, and DELETE. I just want to make sure that only admins can create, update, and remove resources. Since a desktop program will be the only way to use admin methods, I am not concerned about ease of implementing the admin methods into a website.

Comment: Why don't you use some form of externalized authorization? Spring Security? XACML?

Comment: I'm rather new to REST all together. What would be a good place to start with that? I also thought about using basic authentication over headers since I'm already using HTTPS